# How to produce average for calendar months when spreadsheet quantity spans months?

Tags: excel, math, formula, spreadsheet

I am documenting my historic home energy consumption. I am entering in to a Google drive spreadsheet the kWh figure found in gas bills from the last few years.

I have come far - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AuQU5u-2PP8NdC1iNFJVNFVxeDE2WHhVdTUtbGNDWnc&output=html (here is the Google Doc - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuQU5u-2PP8NdC1iNFJVNFVxeDE2WHhVdTUtbGNDWnc&usp=sharing)

Now I want to analyse this data in interesting ways, to be aware of my changing consumption over time - principally, *kWh by calendar month*. The problem is, the issued gas bills containing kWh figures span multiple and partial months. eg (Feb 1 to May 11, then 12 May to 6 Aug)...

All data in the sheet is logged on a row containing two key identifiers - period start and end dates - which are formatted as dates.

My question: How can I rationalise this stuff to traverse those awkward multi-month bill figures, to produce some kind of average or mean for kWh used on a calendar-month basis (ie. Feb 2007, Mar 2007)? Is that even mathematically possible or reliable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=YEARFRAC(StartDate, EndDate, [convention])` which will give you the fractional number of years between the dates using a reasonable convention for day count.

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/yearfrac-HP005209344.aspx for more details on various day count conventions available.

Comment: Thank-you. I have updated my sheet with, eg. =YEARFRAC(A3,B3, 4). Now I can see that, yes, August 2007 to February 2008 is about 0.46 of a year. But how do I go further and figure out how much of my multi-month quantities (kWh) to apportion to the calendar months they cut across?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that per-month information doesn't fit your current table structure; to help explain, if you worked out different monthly rates for Feb, May and Jun 2007 (they are different rates) where would you put these numbers in your table?

There are many options, but I believe the best solution is to:
Create a new table with consistent frequency (i.e. consecutive months down column A), then create formulae to interpolate the relevant values from the source table.
I would actually recommend this 'pure' table uses a line per day (rather than per month) because:

1. the maths is easier to get a per-day rate read out of the source
   table
2. you can always aggregate daily data back up to monthly
3. you are not in danger of running out of lines in your sheet

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is doable.
Calculate your cumulative usage (since your bills started) for each gas bill.  Interpolate the cumulative usage for the 1st of each month.  For Feb 2007 = (Mar_1_2007_cumulative - Feb_1_2007_cumulative).

---

Goal "... consumption over time - kWh by calendar month."

Even if you had daily consumption figures, as months like January (31 days) are longer than  February (28/29), charting what you request would show a + bias in long months and - bias in short months.  So let's change the goal to

Goal "... *daily* consumption over time - *kWh/day* by calendar month."

Say you have figures like  where you list the data, usage since last data and you calculate the *cumulative* usage since the beginning of your records set.

```
date         kWH *1  Total*2
Jan 1, 2012  -       0
Mar 3, 2012  100     100
Apr 4, 2012  30      130 
May 2, 2012  35      165
Aug 9, 2012  75      240
Dec 25, 2012 100     340
Jun 7, 2013  200     540
```

*1 energy used since previous period
*2 Sum of total usage

(Ignore the "kWH *1" column for the following)

Now make a table for the first of the month for a year, say 2012, and find in the above table an entry <= the first of the month, and the next entry.

```
Jan 1, 2012 (Jan 1, 2012    0) (Mar 3, 2012  100)
Feb 1, 2012 (Jan 1, 2012    0) (Mar 3, 2012  100)
Mar 1, 2012 (Jan 1, 2012    0) (Mar 3, 2012  100)
Apr 1, 2012 (Mar 3, 2012  100) (Apr 4, 2012  130)
May 1, 2012 (Apr 4, 2012  130) (May 2, 2012  165)
...
Dec 1, 2012 ....
```

As dates can have a serial number, you liner interpolate that serial number into the the 2 date/cumulative_usage pairs.  this provides the cumulation usage to your 1st of the month. That becomes column "Interpolation" for the below table.  The "Days/Month" is straight forward (days form First of the month to the next).   The Usage/Day for a given month is then the (*change* in "Interpolation") / "Days/Month".  E. g. 1-Feb-12 --> (96.8-50.0)/29 = 3.34.

```
Date         Interpolation  Days/Month  Usage/Day  
1-Jan-12     -              31      1.61 
1-Feb-12     50.0           29      3.34 
1-Mar-12     96.8           31      4.10 
1-Apr-12     127.2          30      5.46 
1-May-12     163.8          31
```

All thats left is to chart Usage/Day vs. Date.